# How to crop a region in LIDAR point cloud

Tags: matlab, cloud, crop, point

I have 2 data set point cloud and I want to crop a part of them together.
Because of volume of them is too too large I couldn't crop them with below codes.
Can you help me to how can I crop them?
Used codes are:

```
 selectedl=[];%% last pulse
for i=1:size(indexl)
    selectl=lr(indexl(i),:);
    selectedl=[selectedl;selectl]; 
end
selectedf=[];%% first pulse
for i=1:size(indexf)
selectf=fr(indexf(i),:);
selectedf=[selectedf;selectf];
end
```

Thank U all.

Comment: Do you get an error message? What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit difficult to understand what you want to do, as `lr`, `fr`, `indexl`  and `indexf` are missing.

But assuming something like

```
lr     = rand(5,3) ;
indexl = [2 5] ;
```

I would advise to allocate `selectedl` above the loop

```
selectedl = NaN(length(indexl),size(lr,2)) ;
for i = 1:length(indexl)
   selectedl(i,:) = lr(indexl(i),:) ;
end
```

This might not be needed for this example, but if the data size becomes larger this will speed up the loop.